# MYSQL: Reference foreign keys to composite primary keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Given that I have 3 tables namely institutions, pages and page_content, how to only update cascade the foreign key of updated composite primary key?

`institutions` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `institutions` (
  `inst_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unsigned,
  `inst_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inst_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

inst_id | inst_desc
1       | Institution 1
2       | Institution 2
```

---

`pages` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `page_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inst_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_code`,`inst_id`),
  KEY `inst_id` (`inst_id`),
  KEY `page_code` (`page_code`,`inst_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

page_code   | page_desc   | page_url    | inst_id
course-list | Course List | course/list | 1
course-list | Course List | course/list | 2
```

---

`page_content` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page_content` (
  `page_content_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inst_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_content_code`,`page_code`,`inst_id`),
  KEY `inst_id` (`inst_id`),
  KEY `page_code` (`page_code`,`inst_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

page_content_code | page_code   | text     | inst_id
label-subject     | course-list | Subjects | 1
label-subject     | course-list | Subjects | 2
```

The problem is that when I update `pages.page_code` where `inst_id = 1` to `course-label`, `page_content.page_code` for all `inst_id` becomes `course-label` as well.

It should only update the `page_content.page_code` where `inst_id = 1` since what I have updated is the `pages.page_code` where `inst_id = 1` as well.

Comment: Re `pages`:  A `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE` and is a `KEY`, so get rid of the redundant `KEY`.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking `FOREIGN KEYs` to do something they can't do.